# Own JavaScript not running

Tags: javascript, linux, html

I'm starting to learn HTML5+CSS+JS. It was all going fine on my Windows desktop, but when I try doing something on my Linux notebook, no javascript seems to work.

This is the mini tutorial I followed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/JavaScript

and this is my page with the result: http://www.lele.bbt.net.ar/prueba01/

(As you can see, the JS is not doing a thing).

```js
// JavaScript demonstration
var changeBg = function(event) {
  console.log("method called");
  var me = event.target,
    square = document.getElementById("square");
  square.style.backgroundColor = "#ffaa44";
  me.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  setTimeout(function() {
    clearDemo(me)
  }, 2000);
}

function clearDemo(button) {
  var square = document.getElementById("square");
  square.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  button.removeAttribute("disabled");
}

var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", changeBg);
console.log(button);
```

```css
#square {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 2px inset gray;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
button {
  padding: .5em 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Mozilla CSS Getting Started - JavaScript demonstration</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>JavaScript sample</h1>
  <div id="square"></div>
  <button>Click Me</button>

</body>

</html>
```

(Here it works, but for some reason, not when I do it on my computer).

I don't know if it can be a priviledge problem or something like that (js has read/write priviledges, not execute. But I guess that's how it should be)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's because the script can't find the button.
You load your script before everything else is loaded, which is fine. But you can have problems like this. **To avoid this kind of problems you load the JavaScript file after the HTML.**

At the moment if you try to print the var "button" you will receive "null".
The Chrome console when you open the page gives you this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

That means that it is trying to read the property of the button, which is `null`.

Move the `script` tag to the very end, just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<body>
  <h1>JavaScript sample</h1>
  <div id="square"></div>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: What T.J. makes sense plus it's true: I've just tried the original code on my Windows laptop and it didn't work just like it didn't on your computer. After I changed the script include tag to the buttom just before the closing body tag, it did work in a hearbeat.

Comment: You sir, deserve a cookie!
Thanks so much! I was stuck on this for a long time, it never occured to me it was due to this (I read on mozilla developer tools the "button = null" thing, but I didn't  associated it with the position of the script)
I still don't know why it sometimes works (as in the example).